# TIdTCPClient app crash on android 6

Tags: android, delphi, crash, indy

On Delphi XE8 i have simple function to check internet connection:

```
function TForm1.Internet: boolean;
begin
 result:=false;
 try
  IdTCPClient1.ReadTimeout:=2500;
  IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout:=2500;
  IdTCPClient1.Port:=80;
  IdTCPClient1.Host:='google.pl';
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  result:=true;
 except
 result:=false;
end;
end;
```

Everything works just fine in older android version but in andoid 6 the app just crashes (close) when i call IdTCPClient1.Connect.
Then I learned that this is blocking function and it has to be in worker thread so i wrote something like this:

```
type
  TTest = class(TThread)
 private
 { Private declarations }
  protected
 procedure Execute; override;
end;
```

and in the implementation section:

```
procedure TThread.Execute;
begin
  try
   Form1.IdTCPClient1.ReadTimeout:=2500;
   Form1.IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout:=2500;
   Form1.IdTCPClient1.Port:=80;
   Form1.IdTCPClient1.Host:='google.pl';
   Form1.IdTCPClient1.Connect;
   Form1.IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;

   except
    showmessage('no internet connection');
   end;
  end; 

 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   Test : TTest;
  begin
    Test := TTest.Create(False);
  end;
```

but unfortunately the app is still closing on android 6 when i call TForm1.Button1Click  (on windows and older android versions works just fine)
Please help me ;)

Comment: You cannot use showmessage() in a thread if it indeed shows a message. But showmessage is your own function so how would we know what it does?

Comment: For the rest it looks as if you are not looking at the logcat. You can find the whole story there.

Comment: @greenapps: `ShowMessage()` is a Delphi RTL function in the `FMX.Dialogs` unit.

Comment: @masohaso: the second version of your code can't possibly crash the app when clicking the button. There is nothing in `Button1Click()` itself that can crash, and if a crash were happening inside of the `TThread` object then `TThread` would silently catch the exception and kill the thread.  So something else is going on.

Comment: Many problems with your threaded version. You cannot access visual components from within a thread, so you can't use `form1`. Your TIdHTTP component should be created in code within your thread. Also, remove ShowMessage, because you can't show dialogs from within a thread either. No visual controls (including dialogs) from within a thread. Use File->New->Other->Thread object, and read the large comment that the IDE adds at the top. You're also eating all exceptions, whether they're related to TIdHTTP or not. How will you know if something else is wrong if you throw away every single exception?

Comment: Thank You for every advice, but still it doesn't work. In my opinion nobody knows why indy component(supplied as standard with XE8) compile with Delphi XE8 works on every android version older than 6.0 but didnt work on 6.0.  Beer for the one who writes the code on XE8 with a working indy on android 6.0 (simple internet check connection) ;) Regards ;)